Button click on site is resulting in page error
Getting a Page error because of this code for some reason:
if (button) { button.click() } - button exists and is getting clicked. I'm using a chrome extension to implement this.
Idk why it's happening. Here's the specific error: Page Error Internal Server Error. (id: VPS|eb58994b-3c1c-43a5-bbfd-de3114256464) - Does anybody know what to do? Same for the other buttons on the page I'm working with. Here's the site I'm working with. It's a workday job app portal: https://wd3.myworkdaysite.com/en-US/recruiting/takeaway/grubhubcareers/job/New-York-City-Bryant-Park-Office/Machine-Learning-Intern---Diner_R_038062/apply/autofillWithResume?q=intern
